# Rewrite only first bytes of file

Tags: c, file, file-io, url-rewriting, stdio

I have small problem with rewriting first 2,5KB of file. My code should read 2KB and 512 bytes  to dynamically allocated memory and then rewrite specific bytes of much larger file.

```
f = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
if(f==NULL)
    printf("File doesn't exist!");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
data = calloc(2*1024+512, 1);
fread(data, 1, 2*1024+512, f);
fclose(f);

f = fopen(argv[1], "ab");
if(f==NULL)
    printf("File doesn't exist!");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(data, 1, 446, f);
fseek(f, 512, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(((char*)data)+512, 1, 2*1024, f);
fclose(f);
```

When I try to use `wb` mode, it erases contents of second file. When I use `ab` mode and seek to the start of file, previous content is appended on the end.

Is there any way (using standard C libraries) to rewrite file contents without appending and copying remaining content of written file? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"rb"` mode opens the file positioned at the start; the initial `fseek()` is redundant.

The second open with `"ab"` opens the file for writing in append mode.  All writes will occur at the end of the file, regardless of what `fseek()` operations you do beforehand.

You could sensibly use mode `"rb+"` to open the file once for both reading and writing:

```
if ((f = fopen(argv[2], "rb+")) != 0)
{
    char *data = calloc(2*1024+512, 1);   // Missing error check
    fread(data, 1, 2*1024+512, f);        // Missing error check
    // Modify data?
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(data, 1, 446, f);
    fseek(f, 512, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite(((char*)data)+512, 1, 2*1024, f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

The code should check that the `calloc()` succeeds before using `data`; it should also error check the `fread()` to be sure it got the expected data.  Presumably, something in the middle will modify the data read from the file.

---

ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (the current C standard) has this to say about the modes for `fopen()` — and the previous standards said much the same except for the `x` flag, which is new in C11:

> §7.21.5.3 The `fopen` function
>
> ¶3 The argument `mode` points to a string. If the string is one of the following, the file is open in the indicated mode. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.<sup>271)</sup>
>
> - `r` open text file for reading
> - `w` truncate to zero length or create text file for writing
> - `wx` create text file for writing
> - `a` append; open or create text file for writing at end-of-file
> - `rb` open binary file for reading
> - `wb` truncate to zero length or create binary file for writing
> - `wbx` create binary file for writing
> - `ab` append; open or create binary file for writing at end-of-file
> - `r+` open text file for update (reading and writing)
> - `w+` truncate to zero length or create text file for update
> - `w+x` create text file for update
> - `a+` append; open or create text file for update, writing at end-of-file
> - `r+b` or `rb+` open binary file for update (reading and writing)
> - `w+b` or `wb+` truncate to zero length or create binary file for update
> - `w+bx` or `wb+x` create binary file for update
> - `a+b` or `ab+` append; open or create binary file for update, writing at end-of-file
>
> <sup>271)</sup> If the string begins with one of the above sequences, the implementation might choose to ignore the
> remaining characters, or it might use them to select different kinds of a file (some of which might not
> conform to the properties in §7.21.2).

Comment: +1 *Thank you* for saving my sanity, sir (not the first time). (and a note for the OP, make sure you follow the documentation and call `fflush()` after a write-operation before doing an immediate-followup read-operation when opening the file in this mode. Its important.

Comment: @WhozCraig: a `fflush()` works, but so do the file positioning operations: `fseek()`, `rewind()`, `fsetpos()`.  (And thanks for the complement.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, it was mentioned for the specific case where you immediately follow a `fwrite()` with an `fread()`. Any of them should validate the buffering. I suppose even an `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_CUR)` would work (though I'm not sure what the point would be). Thanks again, *very* much for reminding me how i did this in the past.

Answer (score 3):

You want `ab+`. The `+` signifies update mode. If the file exists, it will simply be opened and the contents not changed. `wb` by itself will simply erase the original file and create a new one.

Comment: So.. the "destroys contents" in the table at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) is inaccurate for `"w+"` ? The `b` is a Windows thing, so is not mentioned here. That would seem to be a pretty important mistake if it isn't right.

Comment: `If a file with the same name already exists its contents are discarded and the file is treated as a new empty file` - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/
It erases contents of my file.

Comment: That's why you use the `+` option, which leaves the original contents intact UNTIL you change them.

Comment: But I need to change them. I need to rewrite them. Is there some trick with it?

Comment: You're thinking about this too hard. fopen with `wb+`, seek to whatever part of the file you want to change, then fwrite().

Comment: I did it, but contents of my file were erased.

Comment: Ok, I stil don't get it, Marc. How does [this sample](http://ideone.com/OeVnmA) *not* confirm what the OP is seeing, that "wb+" does, as the sites indicate, destroy the existing content of he file? Note: its on IDEOne, so file IO is not allowed; you'll have to copy it locally to test it, but its a pretty brain-dead example. I know I'm missing something, but I don't see what.

Comment: Man, this is what I get for trying to be at work after a very late concert. My apologies. Use `ab+` instead. That opens in read/write mode. You'll be able to fseek to to wherever you need to write, but by default it will try to write at the end of the file.

Comment: yeah, i tried that too. same sample, but wrote 1K, then opened in "ab+", then `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)`, then wrote 100 bytes, fflushed, and closed. Ending file was 1124 bytes long and the 100-byte write was appended; not overwriting the first 100 bytes as intended. Thing is, *i've done this correctly before, but can't for the life of me remember how*. It may have been with the low-level `open()` family.

Comment: `"ab+"` is not the answer; it ensures that all writes occur at the end of the file because it is append mode.  `"rb+"` should be the answer, with a single `fopen()` being used.  See my answer.